# I want to know every way I can use my new ssd to speed up my computer

Tags: ssd

I really want suggestions so I can use that speed fully to my advantage. I have an ssd with read/write speeds of over 500 megabytes per second and sata 3 at 6gbps though I only have a 1.9ghz amd cpu and 4gb of ram. My boot time is already top notch (7 seconds usually) but I want to know how I could use it to make everything else fly.

Comment: If everything is on the SSD, what else is left? Are you also using an HDD? If so, what are you keeping on it?

Comment: Besides putting all of your files on your SSD, the only thing I can think of is maybe using it for swap as well, but it seems like you have a fair amount of ram. Your CPU seems a little slow for you other specs, though.

Comment: it's a 240gb ssd that I have everything on. I have a fresh install right now except that I'm trying to move over my kde settings

Comment: also I have 8gb of swap on it

Comment: This is OT...  Please Flag.

Comment: how? I want to know how I can speed up ubuntu and use tweaks FOR UBUNTU to speed up the ui and such

Comment: like changing how i/o is handled to boost reaction speed as a hit on gross write speed really isn't of concern

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this site because it is too broad.  This site is intended more for specific questions related to Ubuntu, such as how to achieve a certain task, or fix a certain problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps enabling TRIM for SSD may improve its speed.

(note, I've never does this, so I don't know if it will work)

Exerted:

> Why TRIM is Important
>   We’ve covered why TRIM is important before. When you delete a file on an old, magnetic hard drive, the computer simply marks that file as deleted. The file’s data sticks around on the hard drive — that’s why deleted files can be recovered. The computer will eventually overwrite the deleted files when it overwrites their sectors with new data.
>
> Solid-state drives (SSDs) work differently. Whenever you write a file to an SSD, the computer must first erase any data in the sectors it’s writing the data to. It can’t just “overwrite” the sectors in one operation — it must first clear them, then write to the empty sectors.
>
> This means that an SSD will slow down over time. Writing to the SSD’s sectors will be quick the first time. After you delete some files and try to write to it again, it will take longer. This is a big part of the reason Google’s original Nexus 7 slowed down so much over time. Google fixed this by implementing TRIM in Android 4.3. (Android also uses the Linux kernel.)
>
> With TRIM enabled, the operating system tells the SSD each time it deletes a file. The drive can then erase the sectors containing the file’s contents, so writing to the sectors will be quick in the future.

Source:
http://www.howtogeek.com/176978/ubuntu-doesnt-trim-ssds-by-default-why-not-and-how-to-enable-it-yourself/

Comment: That article is well over a year old. Ubuntu 14.04 is supposed to have TRIM enabled by default for some (most?) SSDs: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215407, http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/trim-enabled-by-default-for-ssds-on.html